# Test Class for a VF Page Controller w/ Void Method

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, custom-controller

Trying to write a test class for below method. Essentially this method will fire "onchange" on the VF page to rerender a new query and new picklist.

```
public void calculateAwards(){
    awards = new List<SelectOption>();
    if(atype == null || atype == ''){
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Select a Card Type'));
        return;
    }
    list<Awards__c> award= [SELECT Id, name FROM Awards__c WHERE Awards__c.type__c =:atype and Awards__c.Active__c = TRUE Order by name];
    awards.add(new selectoption('', '—-Select Award—-'));
    for( Awards__c a:award){
        awards.add(new selectoption(a.id,a.name));
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far for this test method?

Comment: a place to start is by reading this page from the VF Dev Guide - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing void methods on controllers is not that different from none-void methods, first take a look at the Salesforce topic, [Testing Custom Controllers and Controller Extensions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm).

In the case of a **void method** you are **asserting** the state or **member variables** of your controller class instread of the return value of the method. In your case the **awards** member variable by the looks of it. Prior to calling the method, you will also need to set a member variable to emulate the user entering a value into whatever field is bound to your **atype**.

Roughly speaking i'd expect a test to do something like this...

1. Insert your test data
2. Construct the controller
3. Set controller member variables (emulating user entering field values)
4. Call the void controller method bound to button or event
5. Assert controller member variables (emulating what the user sees on the page)

The code might look something like this...

```
insert testAwards;

System.startTest();
MyController controller = new MyController();
controller.atype = 'atypevalue';
controller.calculateAwards();
System.assertEquals(10, controller.awards.size());
System.stopTest();
```

Comment: Your assert should be `controller.awards.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could call the method and assert that `awards` is set as you are expecting.

You can try setting `atype` to null and and an empty String as well and verify `awards` is empty.

You could also setup different combinations of `Awards__c` records with different combinations of Active__c flags to verify that the correct ones are being added to `awards` and that they are also sorted by `Name`.